# Acurracy = 0 using tensorflow on tabular data

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am new to machine learning and trying to apply [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/keras/feature_columns) tutorial to my tabular data. My input is a pandas dataframe containing the features (I encoded the categorical columns as floats) and a pandas series containing the labels, which are ints. 
This is my code:

```
def df_to_dataset(dataframe, labels, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
   ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe), labels))
   if shuffle:
      ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
  return ds

feature_columns = []
# numeric cols
for header in list(X_train):
  feature_columns.append(feature_column.numeric_column(header))
feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)
batch_size = 32
train_ds = df_to_dataset(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size)
val_ds = df_to_dataset(X_val, y_val, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
test_ds = df_to_dataset(X_test,y_test, shuffle=False, 
  batch_size=batch_size)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
   feature_layer,
   layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
   layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
   layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'],)
          #run_eagerly=True)

model.fit(train_ds,
      validation_data=val_ds,
      epochs=5)
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_ds)
print("Accuracy", accuracy)
```

First of all, when I print the shape of the datasets, all feature shapes are shown as (?,). I looked that up, but it didn't really get, what that meant, so I moved on.
When executing the model, I got the following output:

```
W0625 16:28:50.013361 140172694484864 deprecation.py:323] From 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py:180: 
add_dispatch_support.<locals>.wrapper (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) 
is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
Epoch 1/5
2437/2437 [==============================] - 12s 5ms/step - loss: 
-368933040.3744 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: -1374389959.0878 - val_acc: 
0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/5
2437/2437 [==============================] - 11s 4ms/step - loss: 
-4239125012.7993 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: -8055676778.8942 - val_acc: 
0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/5
2437/2437 [==============================] - 11s 4ms/step - loss: 
-14449097654.0468 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: -21844830544.8532 - val_acc: 
0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/5
2437/2437 [==============================] - 11s 4ms/step - loss: 
-32560744568.1740 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: -44181551604.6596 - val_acc: 
0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/5
2437/2437 [==============================] - 11s 4ms/step - loss: 
-60235093753.8022 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: -76823729189.8015 - val_acc: 
0.0000e+00
1219/1219 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 
-78553874677.2896 - acc: 0.0000e+00
Accuracy 0.0
```

Obviously something is wrong, but I don't even know where to begin debugging this, so any tips are welcome!
Edit: the labels I am trying to predict are point scores from 80 to 100. Because of this, I switched from binary_crossentropy to mean_squared error. Now the loss is still very large, but positive and the accuracy is still 0

Comment: From your example, I see that the loss grows bigger with every step.
When you switched from binary_crossentropy to MSE, does your loss start converging to zero? Or is it the same pattern as in the example?

Answer (score 1):

Accuracy is for classification problems (and usually not the best metric anyway). Now, with integer outputs you could treat this as a multiclass classification problem, but you'd need to encode things properly for tensorflow to understand. I'd guess (without really knowing your data, mind) that you'd be better off with regression (so no cross-entropy either).

You also can't use a sigmoid activation on the last layer; it's forcing output predictions between 0 and 1. If you go for regression, you won't need to adjust you true labels, you can use MSE as your metric, and you can just put a linear activator on the last layer.